# How to execute a java class form a particular package using Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

have a project in eclipse with several package and converted to maven.
How can i execute one java class from a particular package, the java class share methods from other java class which are in the same package.

for example:

```
Selenium_Test
   |
 src/test/java
      |
      package1
         | (Test1.class, Utility.class, date.class.etc...)
      package2
      package3
```

What i want is to execute the Test1.java.
I tried this command `mvn -Dtest=Test1` , it executes the Test1 but i could not find Utility.class, Date.class

The error is :

```
mvn -Dtest=Test1 test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Selenium_Test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ NumberGenerator ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Selenium_Test\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ NumberGenerator ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ NumberGenerator ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Selenium_Test\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ NumberGenerator ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ NumberGenerator ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Selenium_Test\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running Package1.Test1

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 335.371 sec <<< FAILURE!
Package1.Test1  Time elapsed: 335.37 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40'
System info: host: 'ACQUI-0205', ip: '10.30.163.172', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_11'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:593)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:614)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:468)
        at Package1.Utility.<init>(Utility.java:101)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:7057 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:140)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.fallBackExecute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:215)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:184)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:165)
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:362)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:572)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
        ... 40 more
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Use the exec plugin?

Comment: Can you show code snippet of import statements and error stack trace?

Comment: I don't use exec plugin and the code is too large to paste here

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) for this purpose.

This is how you activate the plugin in your project pom:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <!-- To define the plugin version in your parent POM -->
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        ...
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <!-- To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

You then may call your class using the following goal:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Main"
```

When writing test code please consider using the [JUnit](http://junit.org/) or [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) frameworks and the [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) to execute them with your build.

Comment: What represent the mainClass?

Comment: i tried this mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="package1" and i hve this error Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java(default-cli) on project Selenium_Test: The parameters 'mainClass' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:java are missing or invalid ->[Help 1]

Comment: I found the problem, it comes from itext pdf librairies, i use itext pdf 5.5.3 and i have to find extrajars for this version, i did not find yet.